# How to authenticate MVC user login form with web API JWT token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, model-view-controller, jwt

I'm new to MVC, having brought our application over from Angular, so apologies for limited knowledge.

Our MVC app is set up to provide a JWT token via API upon successful authentication. (Postman tested)

Currently posting the form to the API, however validation doesn't apply and a successful 'login' loads the api url with the token as an xml.

I would like to know how to:

Handle errors (currently throws server error 'String reference not set to an instance of a String.') cshtml page doesn't validate

Store the token and correctly handle requests

Where to store code, in controller and what to have on the page.

What is needed to store the token instead of loading the XML page

I'm not sure what difference holding a JWT token has throughout the site vs what MVC authentication already has

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you written any code for this? You need to share the code here and explain the issue you are facing in that.

Comment: You ca read about this at http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

Answer (score 0):

Here are answers as you asked:

1. For handling errors you can use Error filter attribute in Web API similar to MVC.
2. There is no need to store the token on server, you just need to store it on the client and send it with every request. You can store it in HTML tag.
3. Now you need to have two separate projects, one for server side code(Web API) and one for UI. And you can easily identify which logic you want on the server and which on client.
4. You need to write a get method to get the token for your API.

The major difference between holding the JWT and MVC authentication - You need to keep session active on the server in case of MVC authentication but in token you don't need to. In this way its easier for you to balance load for your application as you don't need session on each load balance server.